# CoreBluetooth: testing state preservation and restoration

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, state-restoration

I am using Xcode 7 and I would like to understand how to test "State Preservation and restoration" in iOS9 using a BLE accessory and CoreBluetooth framework (please not that I have already found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797665/ios-corebluetooth-state-preservation-and-restoration), but I feel the need to understand this in more depth).

I need the app to automatically transfer some data from the accessory only when the user's phone is in range, also in case the app was not previously running.

I tried to break down this in three scenarios reflecting different variation of this use case, namely scenario A, scenario B and scenario C.

**Would someone be able to explain me the basic steps needed to test the following scenarios?**

**Also do these scenario make sense?**

- scenario A:

  1 - app discover accessory and stores the accessory information

  2 - app / user exits accessory range

  3 - app is killed by user

  4 - user re-enters accessory range whilst App is not running.

  5 - Expected event: I expect state restoration to be activated (**willRestoreState** method being called in CentralManager as well as **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** in AppDelegate.

  From here I should be able to get the list of peripherals including the accessory and decide whether or not I want to connect to it.

  6 - If I decided to connect then I expect the app to keep running in background (as background mode was activated).

How can I test this scenario?

---

- scenario B:

  1 - app discover accessory and stores the accessory information

  2 - app connects to accessory and sends request to a characteristic to start transferring data

  3 - app is receiving data from accessory

  4 - app / user exits accessory range

  5 - app goes in background mode

  6 - user re-enters accessory range whilst App is running in background mode.

  5 - Expected event: I expect state restoration to be activated (**willRestoreState** method being called in CentralManager as well as **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** in AppDelegate.

  From here I should be able to get the list of peripherals including the accessory and see that the status is **CONNECTED**. I should then re-request the data stream (I assume there is no way to resume the previous stream, correct?)

  6 - app should be continuing stream in background

How can I test this scenario?

---

- scenario C:

  1 - app discover accessory and stores the accessory information

  2 - app connects to accessory and sends request to a characteristic to start transferring data

  3 - app is receiving data from accessory

  4 - app / user exits accessory range

  5 - app goes in background mode

  6 - user kills the app

  7 - user re-enters accessory range whilst App is not running

  8 - Expected event: I expect state restoration to be activated (**willRestoreState** method being called in CentralManager as well as **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** in AppDelegate.

  From here I should be able to get the list of peripherals including the accessory and reconnect to it and re-request the data transfer (resume it as for scenario B).

  9 - I expect the app to keep running in background (as background mode was activated) and app should be continuing stream in background

How can I test this scenario?

Hope is not too confusing.

Comment: Wanted to know if you have find answers for your questions. I am curious about the same thing. From [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW5), I think it might be achievable.

Answer (score 1):

For scenario A I doubt you can do anything at all. If the user kills your app by double-clicking Home button and swiping the app up, the app is gone and doesn't participate in all these fancy Bluetooth chitchats anymore. Same holds for the app that was never launched - iOS won't tell it anything and/or try to wake it up.

In scenario B you will most likely not need to deal with `willRestoreState`, because modern smartphones (5s, 6) don't seem to kill your suspended app even after launching a bunch of heavy apps on top of it. The app will just quietly disconnect when you leave the accessory range. Then, if you will instruct it to immediately start scanning for the accessory again (in `didDisconnectPeripheral`), it will do so for ages. Not too often, but still. So, when you'll enter the accessory range again, the iPhone will eventually connect to it and trigger all the required callbacks. `willRestoreState` seems to only be relevant for iPhone 4s, maybe iPhone 5, but I didn't play with this functionality for really long to be absolutely sure.

If you really need to test `willRestoreState` scenario, you can A) add local notifications to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and `willRestoreState` to make sure they're triggered and B) run your app in Xcode and then stop it by pressing CMD+. or clicking square button in Xcode. This will cause the app to terminate the same way as the system would kill it on memory issues, so you should see your notifications. From now on, you can write the code, add log statements and observe what happens in the device log.

Another way to test state restoration is invoking `kill(getpid(), SIGKILL);` after tapping a button.

Scenario C - sorry, same story. If the user deliberately kills your app, you're screwed. Tell him not to.